# OCUnit Tests giving errors in classes not being tested

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode4, ocunit

I have written an OCUnit test, which ran fine in Xcode 3.2, and now I'm having problems with it in Xcode 4. It tests a single static function `X` in class `A`, which doesn't call any classes or functions (outside of library functions). The only other code that should need to be called is the static constructor, which initializes two static variables, but again, those are hardcode values (arrays) that don't call any other classes, or functions of class `A`.

And yet, I had to include the .m, .mm, and .c files for all classes that it imports, and that they import, and so on, to solve the **_OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassB", referenced from:** errors. I don't recall having to do any of that in Xcode 3, but fine, no problem, I got it to compile. Now, I'm getting errors originating from class `B`'s `+[B initialize]`.

Why is the static constructor getting called on a class that is not referenced in any way? How can I fix this, ideally without changing my classes to acommodate the testing?

**Update**

To further figure out what's going on, I commented out all my test cases and the `#import "A.h"` to see what would happen. I added a single simple unit test:

```
- (void) testSomething {
    STAssertTrue(NO, @"did it work?");
}
```

*Still*, my `+[B initialize]` gets called and fails. It seems that OCUnit is crawling through all of my classes, and their `+initialize` methods are getting called in the process. This makes no sense to me - how can I disable this behavior?

Here is the stack trace before my own code gets called, in case it helps:

```
#7  _class_initialize ()
#8  prepareForMethodLookup ()
#9  lookUpMethod ()
#10 objc_msgSend ()
#11 +[NSObject(SenTestRuntimeUtilities) senIsASuperclassOfClass:] ()
#12 +[NSObject(SenTestRuntimeUtilities) senAllSubclasses] ()
#13 +[SenTestSuite updateCache] ()
#14 +[SenTestSuite suiteForBundleCache] ()
#15 +[SenTestSuite testSuiteForBundlePath:] ()
#16 +[SenTestProbe specifiedTestSuite] ()
#17 +[SenTestProbe runTests:] ()
#18 <????> ()
#19 <????> ()
#20 <????> ()
#21 <????> ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a number of problems with xcode 4 and my unit test suites as well.

I'd have to see your source to know what's going on in your case, but OCUnit does do a lot of stuff through reflection on classes.  That's how it figures out to run methods that start with "test".  So it makes some sense that it's inspecting your classes, causing their class initializers to fire.

I know this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but if the errors in B's +initialize are because it's relying on some sort of expected application state, you may really want to consider refactoring +initialize.  It shouldn't be dependent on anything outside the class itself for this exact reason... you have no guarantees on when it will fire or what state things will be in.

Comment: Thanks, and that makes sense, but should I even need to include B.m, when its code isn't used by the test or the functions in class A that the test calls? I'm pretty sure I didn't have to in Xcode 3, which is why this never came up.

Comment: @Dov - I'm still getting my arms around some of this too.  I would check out your unit test's "Scheme" though.  These are new with Xcode 4, and I've found that it doesn't always auto-create them appropriately.  If you edit the scheme, there's one option in particular "Find Implicit Dependencies" in your Build -> Build options that might be trying to pull in the other project.

Comment: Turning "Find Implicit Dependencies" off didn't help. For now I guess I will make sure that all my +initialize functions run independently of other configuration. What's making that tougher in my case is that I'm using Core Data, and that necessitates a bunch of shared state. I'll have to handle it differently.

Comment: @Dov - Ah, yeah that'd get complicated.  I think it's good design not to rely on +initializers whenever possible anyway, so hopefully those changes won't be a negative for your code.  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I ended up using a workaround that has, so far, proved satisfactory. I posted it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

DougW is correct, that I'm doing things in my +initialize method that probably shouldn't be in there. In any case, I wasn't ready to refactor that only so my unit tests would run.

I used the code below to skip that code, which wasn't required by my unit tests in the first place. I hope this helps someone else out there, as it would be useful in any function, not just the static initializer.

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    if (NSClassFromString(@"SenTestSuite")) {
        NSLog(@"Not initializing 'B' class, because unit tests are running");
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The OCUnit's behaviour of going through each class (and hence calling +initialize:) is very annoying in one hand; but on the other hand it pushes you to come up with better & decoupled designs! Thanks for the question and the answer, it also helped me to solve a unit testing problem.

Comment: One more note about your workaround: It may not be the best approach because it makes you change your actual code. I think a better solution would be use a mocking framework. More on this at: http://scn.sap.com/message/13574536